# How to stop Chrome from asking if I meant to go to a different site?

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I go to uniLy.com (a service used by my employer), Chrome tells me that attackers are everywhere, constantly targeting me, and that my life depends on me being absolutely certain that I didn't mean to go to uniTy.com instead.

[image]

How do I stop this?

The dialog doesn't have a "don't ask again" checkbox on it, and I searched around through the options to no avail.

Chrome 107, 64-bit, Windows 10

Comment: On a fresh installation of Chrome on my personal laptop, I didn't see that issue - it just went straight to the site.  In Settings > Privacy and Security > Safe Browsing, I turned on Enhanced protection and still didn't see any issue.  Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Screenshot added.